# How can I make a MediaStyle notification without a background colour?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

#### Background

I'm using [`MediaStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle) to make a notification with inline buttons:

[image: Notification with inline buttons]

#### Problem

On the Android 5 and 6 emulators, the notification has a coloured background, but I want it to have a normal background like other notifications on the device.

[image: MediaStyle notification with coloured background on Android 5]

#### Code

Here is the code I'm  using:

```java
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannels.ID_CONTROLS)
    .setColor(context.getColor(R.color.main))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_upright_filled)
    .setContentTitle(context.getText(R.string.app_name_full))
    .setContentText(context.getText(R.string.user_rotation_upright))
    .addAction(
        R.drawable.app_left_side,
        context.getText(R.string.user_rotation_left_side),
        leftSidePendingIntent
    )
    .addAction(
        R.drawable.action_turn_off,
        context.getText(R.string.action_turn_off),
        turnOffPendingIntent
    )
    .addAction(
        R.drawable.app_right_side,
        context.getText(R.string.user_rotation_right_side),
        rightSidePendingIntent
    )
    .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
    )
    .build()
```

#### Question

How can I make the notification use a normal background on Android 5 and 6 so it looks like a normal notification? I need to use [`MediaStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle) to make the inline buttons in the notification.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `setColor()` call?

Comment: @CommonsWare, when I remove `setColor()` then it changes the background from my custom colour to dark grey, so it still stands out compared to normal notifications

Comment: As with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552272/how-can-i-make-a-mediastyle-notification-without-a-large-icon), device manufacturers and Google control those things. If they want to put an animated background of a unicorn behind your notification, they can. And those rules can vary by style, should you elect to use one, as you are doing here.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks, sounds like I'll have to do a custom notification

Comment: In some respects, that will make things worse. It will guarantee you consistency between devices. But, in this question, your concern was blending in with the other notifications... and a custom view will rarely do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare, true. What would you recommend for this situation? I need a notification that blends in with other notifications and has inline controls.

Comment: I am unaware of any way to guarantee that presentation. Personally, I recommend dropping the "inline controls" aspect.